# Jackson: allowing nested or "flat" collection when deserializing

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a service that ingest a Json payload and process it further.
The payload may or may not have nested collections. Example:

```
// with nested collections

{"customers": [
   {
     "name":"John",
     "invoices":[
        {
         "id":"1234",
         "items":[
         { 
           "invoice-id":"1234",
           "sku":"abdd"
         },
         { 
           "invoice-id":"1234",
           "sku":"d431"
         }]

        }, 
        {
         "id":"455",
         "items":[
         { 
           "invoice-id":"455",
           "sku":"j3dj"
         },
         { 
           "invoice-id":"455",
           "sku":"dee8"
         }]
        }
     ]
   },
   {
     "name":"Bob"
     ...
   }
]}
```

```
// without nested collection

{"customers": [
   {
     "name":"John",
     "invoices":[
        {
         "number":"1234"
        },
        {
         "number":"455"
        }
      ],
      "items":[
       { 
         "invoice-id":"1234",
         "sku":"abdd"
       },
       { 
         "invoice-id":"1234",
         "sku":"d431"
       },
       { 
         "invoice-id":"455",
         "sku":"j3dj"
       },
       { 
         "invoice-id":"455",
         "sku":"dee8"
       }]

   },
   {
     "name":"Bob"
   }
]}
```

I would like to be able to handle both type of payloads with a single Java object. The approach I have in mind is to use a custom deserializer, but I was wondering if there was a simpler annotation-based approach.